# UL is not the height it should be

Tags: html, css

I have a nav that includes a drop down.

```
<ul>
<li class="n1">Nav 1</li>
<li class="n2">Nav 2</li>
<li class="n3">Nav 3
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li>DropDown 1</li>
    <li>DropDown 2</li>
    <li>DropDown 3</li>
</ul>
```

I wish to add spacing below the nav, so I use margin-bottom.

But the margin is not correct, it's like the UL is not it's full height, I fix this with:

```
overflow: hidden
```

But then the hidden drop down gets cut off.

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: JSfiddle please. You should know this by now.

Comment: As I correctly understanding what you are trying. You should change your margin to padding and delete overflow. But it will be perfect if you provide some code

Comment: Changed it to padding, same issue.

Comment: Please provide us some code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using padding. That will allow you some extra room around each element.

Comment: No this doesn't work either. For some reason the UL element is not residing to the elements that are inside of it.

Comment: And is that with every browser?

Comment: Just testing Google chrome atm.

Comment: Hmm, I would suggest testing it in another browser too, sometimes things don't get aligned properly depending on the browser, I'm not sure exactly why, see how it looks in another browser and if it looks good, that will help you know if it's an issue specifically with chrome.